# php can't display images

Tags: php

I can successfully upload images in my DB but when I want to display them in my application there is a problem with the images. Here is part of my code:

Edit: Added and add_image.php

index.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include("config.php"); 

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

  if($numrows != 0) {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $title = $row['TITLE'];
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $image = $row['IMAGE'];
    echo $title;
    echo "<img src=image.php?id=$id>";
    echo("<hr/><br/><br/>");
  }

  } else {
    die("ERROR");
  }

?>
```

image.php

```
<?php
  include("config.php"); 

  $id = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];

  $image = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ID = $id";
  $image = mysql_query($image) or die('Error, query failed');
  $image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
  $image = $image['image'];
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $image;
?>
```

add_image.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $title = $_POST[title]; 

  if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
      $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    include("config.php"); 

    $query = "INSERT INTO images (TITLE,IMAGE) VALUES ('$title','$content')";

    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 

    echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
  } 
?>
```

Comment: sql injection detected

Comment: There is a `)` in your query.

Comment: why the hell are you storing image in a database ?

Comment: So the `image` field in your db holds actual raw JPG code of your images? That's what you're trying to tell the browser now at least, but I doubt if that's right? Doesn't the field just contain a filename to the image? And as for the SQL injection mentioned above, try casting the id as an integer to avoid people messing with it, like: `$id = (int) $_REQUEST['id'];`

Comment: how the image is entered? What is the datatype of image field? and by the way, you always send image/jpeg content-type header but it's possible that image is in another format

Comment: @animuson why not make it an answer, along with some error logging hints?

Comment: My table has 3 columns - id, image and title of the image. In my database the type of the column image is blob.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Because if that's the answer, this question is too localized and should be closed instead.

Comment: And the problem is not with the )

Comment: @user1107922: You also never run `mysql_query()` in the image.php file.

Comment: Well to me it turned to be not a real question. Why posting the code that is not a real one? Voting to close.

Comment: Update my post with some changes but still doesn't work

Comment: I personally don't recommend to upload images to the database, instead, insert the location of the image to the column "IMAGE" and then just do something like `<img src="<?php echo $image_location; ?>">` where $image_location is the location of the image that you retrieve using a SELECT query. Unless it's extremely necessary, you shouldn't store images in the database, it increases the database load, hence the queries would run slower.

Comment: How many times it is supposed to be updated?

Comment: sql injection still persists though

Comment: oh..my eyes MY EYSSSSSSSS I have gone blind

Comment: So *what* problem do you have with the images?

Answer (score 2):

there are several problems that could be the cause of this.

1. on your insert-script, the colums are named all caps (`IMAGE`, for example) while your select tries to get `image` (lower case) - wich one is actually used in the database? this should be harmonized.
2. you're using `addslashes` to escape strings before interacting with the database (i'm assuming to prevend sql-injections) where you should actually use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). this isn't a problem now, but `addslashes` [might not shelter from sql-injections](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string).
3. when is wrote this answer, you didn't fetch the query result in image.php, wich should be the main problem, but in the meantime you changed it to `$image = mysql_query($image)`, so it might be correct - please simply post your real code insed of constantly changing it here, otherwise it's impossible to tell whats wrong with it.
4. on you add_image.php, the variable `$fileName` is never really used after initializing, while `$title` is used, but never initialized. if this is your real production code, your `image`-column will always be empty, so tehre's nothing to display.
5. assuming `$fileName` and `$title` should be the same and it's just a typo, you shouldn't escape that only it magic_quotes isn't enabled. instead, you should run [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.stripslashes.php) if magic_quotes is enagled to get back the "real" string and then *always* use `mysql_real_escape_string` (see 2.). if possible, you should completely disable magic_quotes, as it only fu**s things up.

Comment: i'm not a native english speaker, so sometimes it's difficult to express oneself - but i tried to rephrase that point to make it more understandable.

Comment: it is not language, it's the matter. what does it mean "addslashes might add slashes to the image-content where they aren't necessary"?

Comment: i was in delusion that addslashes escapes more/other characters than mysql_real_escape_string. this doesn't seem to be the case (sorry for that), so i deleted that part from my answer. the point itself is still valid, because addslashes doesn't commpletely shelter against sql-injections (depending on the configuration, wich we wren't given information about).

Comment: just to let you know. mysql_real_escape_string will do no good by itself. it'll work as intended only if encoding was set by mysql_set_charset(). otherwise it is as dumb as addslashes in every way.